# how to display the field date (type data = date) whose record is above it 12/29/2018

Tags: sql, oracle, select-query

I have trouble in the SQL query to display the data fields whose records are above `29-12-2018` on `Oracle` ,

```
SELECT * FROM 
data 
WHERE date BETWEEN('29-12-2018' AND '01-01-2019')
ORDER BY datetime DESC
```

Comment: Use  `TO_DATE` to convert it to date or simply use [date literals](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/sqlrf/Literals.html#GUID-8F4B3F82-8821-4071-84D6-FBBA21C05AC1) in `yyyy-mm-dd` format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [`to_date()`](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/to_date.php) function to convert your string to a date.

```
SELECT * FROM 
data 
WHERE "date" > to_date('29-12-2018','DD-MM-YYYY')
ORDER BY datetime DESC
```

Comment: Thanks you its work

Answer (score 1):

You can either use

```
SELECT *
  FROM data
 WHERE "date" > to_date('2018-12-29','yyyy-mm-dd') --> needs formatting as the second argument
 ORDER BY datetime DESC
```

or

```
SELECT *
  FROM data
 WHERE "date" > date'2018-12-29' --> literal according to "ISO 8601" standard
 ORDER BY datetime DESC
```

where `date` is converted to `"date"` since, it's a reserved keyword, and not possible to create a table with this column name.

Comment: Thanks you its work

Comment: @DimasPrayoga you're welcome.

Comment: may I ask one more thing barbaros ?

Comment: how to display the field date (type of data date) in the last 3 months

Comment: @DimasPrayoga you need `months_between` function as `where months_between(trunc(sysdate),"date")<= 3`. It doesn't return result for "date" is `date'2018-12-28'`, whereas returns for `date'2018-12-29'`